# How can I make this layout align like it should?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn and practice flexbox by creating my own layouts. I'm not entirely sure why bottom row's `col-1-of-2` won't align with the right `col-1-of-2` in second row. Same with `col-1-of-4`.

Is grid-box better for this because you have more control of the column gap? I tried making the parent margin `5px` and the children padding `5px` and it was close but still not 100% aligned. I'm assuming we have to take the screen size into consideration as well?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.col-1-of-1 {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightblue;
}

.col-1-of-2 {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.col-1-of-3 {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.col-1-of-4 {
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-1">
    <p>col-1-of-1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is grid-box better for this because you have more control of the column gap?

You're getting close to understanding the nature of the problem in this statement.  The problem is that you're taking a layout engine that was built with the goal of allowing elements to grow and shrink their size and space between them in order to get an organic fit, and expecting it to behave like a rigid, grid-like system.

Specifically, the issue arises when you add the `margin` to `.col` elements.  For any given row, you are trying to fit the contents into `100%` `width`, but the contents `width`s add up to `100%` *plus* whatever `margin` exists for the number of elements you've included.

For instance-- the top row will be `100%` plus `2rem` (`margin` on either side).  The next row is two elements of `50%` width, which adds to `100%`, plus the `4rem` tacked on for the `1rem` `margin`s on either sides of the two elements.

`flex` takes care of this for you-- it massages the sizes and gaps in order to make everything fit nice and cleanly in that `100%` width space.  However, things get sticky when you start mixing the `.col-1-of-<num>` types and expecting them to line up nicely-- `flex` is doing its work to make sure they *fit*, which is coming at the cost of having them *align*.

That said, what you want *is* possible with flex.  The solution below simply uses a [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to make sure that the `margin`s are considered when setting the `width` of the element-- instead of `.col-1-of-1` being `100%`, it is `calc(100% - 2em)`, `.col-1-of-2` becomes `calc(50% - 2em)`, and so on.

There may be other ways to approach this using flex that would also work, possibly by playing around with the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property, or the [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property; or you could check out [`grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).  Good luck!

---

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.col-1-of-1 {
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightblue;
}

.col-1-of-2 {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.col-1-of-3 {
  width: calc(33% - 2rem);
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
  justify-content: center;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-1">
    <p>col-1-of-1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-3">
    <p>col-1-of-3</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-4">
    <p>col-1-of-4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-of-2">
    <p>col-1-of-2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see! I knew there was something match related to this answer haha, I was actually messing around with calc() but thought it would go on the margin property, which isn't even possible. I really need to get used to understanding how to get all the calculations right with margins, padding, etc.

Thank you for explaining this though!

So pretty much you'd want to use a grid system for stuff like this?

Comment: I wouldn't want to go so far as to _prescribe_ that grid is _the_ definitive solution here-- you need to weigh your needs against the functions of each layout system.  But what you are trying to achieve certainly _looks_ like a grid-like solution.  That said, if you look at [Bootstap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), they are using `flex` under the hood.